# How to get user input again without exiting if first input is null

Tags: c

I"m trying to fix my function so that if the input is NULL, I can re ask for file input as opposed to exiting the program. Here is what I have so far:

```
void inputGrades(float *arr[MAX_ROWS])
{

    char fileName[20];

    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);//Input file name

    FILE *f = fopen(fileName, "r");//Open file
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found");
        printf("Please enter file name: ");
        exit(0);
```

I'm trying to not have to use an exit statement.

Comment: Do it in a loop. Without `exit` of course.

Comment: Are you sure the array should be an array of pointers, not an array of floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like this?

```
FILE *f = NULL;
while (NULL == f)
{
    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName); //Input file name

    f = fopen(fileName, "r");//Open file
}
```

Comment: `do { ... } while (NULL == f);` may look better, eliminating the first check that will 100% be true.

Comment: The tail of the loop should probably report something like `if (f == NULL) printf("Failed to open file '%s' for reading (%d: %s)\n", fileName, errno, strerror(errno));`.  Since this is interactive, it may be OK to report the problem on `stdout` as I showed; normally, errors should be report to `stderr` (`fprintf(stderr, …)`).  You need to include the headers `<string.h>` for `strerror` and `<errno.h>` for `errno`, of course.  There are those who advocate against reporting the error number; I'm not in agreement with them.

Answer (score 0):

You usually use a loop to do something until some condition is met:

```
FILE* f = NULL;
puts("Please enter file name:");
for (;;) {
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    f = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (!f) puts("File not found, please try again:");
    else break;
}
```

Comment: It's better to put the condition in the loop where possible — IMO, infinite loops should be avoided.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I do agree and I did try that, but this was the clearest version I could find without duplicating anything.